# How can I use SATA hot plugging in Ubuntu 16.04 on an Intel NUC NUC7i7DN board?

Tags: intel, swap, sata, ahci

If I attach a SATA drive to the NUC(NUC7i7DN) after booting into Ubuntu 16.04, the drive is not recognised. Nothing shows up with `lsblk` or `dmesg`.

If I restart, the drive shows up. Additionally, I am able to swap the drive while Ubuntu is running, but only if Ubuntu booted up with a SATA drive present.

Is there a way to get this working? Is it possible Ubuntu is totally disabling the SATA port on boot because it didn't discover any SATA drive?

I have AHCI mode enabled in the BIOS.